# "I wonder whether X, and if so, why." vs "I wonder whether X, and if so, why?"

Tags: punctuation

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

- I wonder whether X, and if so, why**.**
- I wonder whether X, and if so, why**?**

I am unsure what the correct punctuation is in that case.

Comment: Both are correct: "_I wonder  whether you will go, and if so, [I wonder] why [you will go]._" -- "_I wonder  whether you will go, and if so, why [will you go]?_"

Comment: By intonation I would go with the first one. It is a "wondering", not a question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start simple.

> I wonder why.
>   I wonder why?

Normally the correct form is “I wonder why.”. That's indirect speech, so there is no question mark. If spoken alound, “I wonder why?” invites participants in the conversation to volunteer reasons. In writing, it looks a bit strange, but it invites the reader to wonder what the reasons could be (or it could have the ironical meaning of claiming that those reasons are obvious).

> I wonder whether …, and if so, why.
>   I wonder whether …, and if so, why?

It's the same thing, just with a bigger sentence.